# DeletedApiProjectMapError -- Oops Wrong Key passed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps API error: DeletedApiProjectMapError

http://heritagespringsfarms.com/contacts/

This stopped working after an update to Wordpress. Not sure which update as it appears to have been a problem for some amount of time.  Was working fine for many months.

My project still exists in Google api's and the key matches and is unchanged.  Google API console shows the script and geocoding APIs are enabled. Referrer's match

I created a new API key and added it to same project.  tried using new key without referers -- same error.

The key that is being passed to the api does not match either of the keys in my project. Ive flushed the cache and the javascript console shows my map coordinates being passed properly, but the key is wrong.

Help!

Comment: Google thinks the API project that includes the key `key=AIzaSyCKnHFYS1jOE2ArwT4c_Hbm1_IbU6U2xXQ` has been deleted. [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deleted-api-project-map-error).  What key do you think should be valid?  Are you sure your test with the new key(s) actually used it (the page wasn't still being served from the browser's cache)?

Comment: Where did you get an API key AIzaSyCKnHFYS1jOE2ArwT4c_Hbm1_IbU6U2xXQ? Did you create it in your project? I believe you should generate the new one following https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the key was not being properly passed to the API by the wordpress routine that called the API. The key being passed was being pulled from a hard coded variable in the wordpress theme.  The confusing part was that the subroutine call to the api was passing the coordinates but not the key.

Thanks to Zeocodezip for pointing out that the key being passed stayed the same an did not match the changes to the code.

The wordpres theme was a Cherry theme.  Updating to the latest level solved the problem.